# Error building with Sugar ORM and jack

Tags: sugarorm, jack

I'm trying to use Sugar ORM in an Android app that uses jack and Java 8.

I have added the following dependency in `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
```

I get the following error at build time:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Please consider that the building works fine without including the Sugar ORM dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 1.5?

The latest version in the [documentation](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) is 1.4, try changing to:

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
```